# how do I query an unicode string in sqlite3, using Python

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

Say I have an unicode string `u"Robinson Can\u00f3"`, and I stored the string in sqlite3 database using the following:

```
cursor.execute('create table tb (name text)')
cursor.execute('insert into tb values (?)', str')
```

however, if I want to query the unicode string u"Robinson Can\u00f3" from the database, I got nothing.

```
cursor.execute("select * from tb where name = '%s'" % str)
```

but if I query another unicode string which does not contain the unicode, like, u"Kobe Byrant", I can get entry back.

So can anyone tell me how I can deal with the unicode with sqlite3, using Python?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Your query is not an unicode string

Comment: thank you, what do you mean? my query is u'Robinson Can\u00f3', that is an unicode string, right?

Comment: Yes but at least in other languages (where all strings are like python unicode strings, and byte arrays are like python strings) everything is an unicode string and it is only converted to/from bytes on I/O. I feel like since your query is byte array and the parameter is unicode string, it will somehow mess it up I guess.

Comment: okay, so if the database is create like the above, how do I query a foreign language unicode string? I tried your answer, but it does not seem to work. Thank you again!

Comment: I am thinking `cursor.execute(u"select a from b where c = ?", u"äöäöä")`, then the driver should handle encoding on I/O.

Comment: it does not seem to work... and I tried cursor.execute(u"select a from b where c = ?", u"aaooo"), which is working. SO I guess the drive can not do the encoding on I/O

Comment: Have you set the connection charset to UTF-8?

Answer (score 3):

Do *not* use string interpolation when executing SQL code. Use SQL parameters instead:

```
cursor.execute("select * from tb where name = ?", (str,))
```

This applies to any database interaction involving parameters, not just SQLLite.